# For open sets $A,B \subset \mathbb R^n$ the map $x \to \lambda (A \cap (x + B))$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lebesgue-measure

I am working on the following:

For $B \subset \mathbb R^n$, $x \in \mathbb R^n$ define $x + B := \{x + b | b \in B\}$

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb R^n$ be open sets with $\lambda(A) + \lambda(B) < \infty$. Prove the following: $$x \to\lambda (A \cap x + B) \text{ is continuous}$$
*Hint: You may use without proof: The theorem holds true for bounded cuboids.*

I have seen similar questions already but I do not know how to get started involving the hint. With regards to open sets in $\mathbb R^n$ and cuboids I know the 
Theorem: Every open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ can be represented as countable, disjoint union of bounded cuboids

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide more context. What have you tried? What kind of thing is $\lambda$? If $\lambda$ is a number, then your function maps $\Bbb{R}^n$ to the set of open subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$, so you'd need to tell us what topology you are using on that set of open subsets.

Comment: $\lambda$ means to be the Lebesgue (inner) measure.

Comment: So far I know that every continuous function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is measurable - yet I still do not know how to use the provided hint.

Comment: I think you need to use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity and think about approximating the sets involved by finite unions of disjoint cuboids (which is possible because $\lambda(A) + \lambda(B) < \infty$).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just realised we need the hinted approach. Write $A$ and $B$ as countable unions of disjoint cuboids $P_1,P_2,\dots$ and $Q_1,Q_2,\dots$ respectively. Put
\begin{align}
f_{j,k}(x)=\lambda(P_j\cap(t+Q_k)).
\end{align}
Since $\sum\lambda(Q_k)$ is finite, $\lambda(Q_k)\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. Fix $j$. Note that $f_{j,k}\leq\lambda(Q_k)$ for each $k$, so the convergence of $\sum_k f_{j,k}$ is uniform. Since each $f_{j,k}$ is continuous, so is $g_j=\sum_k f_{j,k}$. Apply the same technique to $\sum g_j$ to conclude the proof.

Original: Let $\chi_E$ be the characteristic function of each set $E$. Without loss of generality, assume $x=0$ (otherwise replace $B$ by $x+B$). Given $s\in B$, since $B$ is open,
\begin{align}
\chi_{t+B}(s)=\chi_B(s-t)=1
\end{align}
for all $t$ in some open neighbourhood of $0$. Therefore
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to 0}\chi_{t+B}(s)=1.
\end{align}
By the dominated convergence theorem,
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to0}\lambda(B\cap(t+B))=\lim_{t\to0}\int_B\chi_{t+B}(s)\,ds=\lambda(B).
\end{align}
Put $E_t=B\setminus(t+B)$, then
\begin{align}
\lambda(E_t)=\lambda(B)-\lambda(B\cap(t+B))\to 0
\end{align}
as $t\to 0$. Now
\begin{align}
\lambda(A\cap(t+B))=\lambda(A\cap B\cap (t+B))+\lambda(A\cap E_t).
\end{align}
Since $\lambda(A\cap E_t)\leq\lambda(E_t)$, this term converges to $0$ as $t\to0$. Another application of the dominated convergence theorem shows that
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to0}\lambda(A\cap B\cap(t+B))=\lim_{t\to0}\int_{A\cap B}\chi_{t+B}(s)\,ds=\lambda(A\cap B).
\end{align}